# Overriding base class methods

Tags: c#, c++

Is it possible to override a base class method in C++, like we can do in C# using the override keyword ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Just make the base method `virtual`.
C++ doesn't have an `override` keyword; any method with the same signature (including parameter types and `const`-ness) as a `virtual` base method will override it.

Comment: You do not NEED to make a base class virtual. A virtual base class function allows you to properly use polymorphism. Normally you can just override the base class function, but say you have an array of 'shape' object pointers, you can instance element of that array to a derived object, such as 'square' or 'triangle', if you call a function like draw() it will normally call the base class's draw, unless it is virtual, then it will look at what type is actually being pointed to by the array and call the derived class's function

Comment: @thecoshman: He's asking for the equivalent to C#'s `override` keyword (polymorphism), not C#'s `new` keyword (hiding).  For that, you do need `virtual`.  (even if he doesn't understand the distinction)

Comment: Well, if you look strictly that the keyword `override` in C# it simply is not needed in C++, it is just implicitly implied by the fact that the two functions have the same signature.

Comment: The C# documentation says: "The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or event."  So yes, `virtual` is required

Comment: @thecoshman: A pedantic point: non-virtual member functions cannot be overriden, they can just be hidden

Answer (score 3):

Only in C++0x, the next upcoming standard of the C++ language. In C++03, that is the current C++ you override implicitly, that is you don't mark the overriding method explicitly as an overriding one. But be careful, if you accidentally write another signature but the same name, the base class function will be hidden and not overriden!

```
struct X
{
   virtual void f()  {...};
};

struct Y:X
{
   void f() {...} //overrides X::f
};

struct Z:X
{
   void f() const  {... } //hides X::f!!!
};
```

The only thing that can differ in the functions' declarations is that if in base class the function returns `T1*` ( or `T1&`) and in derived class `T2*` (or `T2&`) and T2 is derived from T1 then it's OK, it's still overrifing, not hiding. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override base class methods; if you use the keyword `virtual` in your base class, the binding of the method will be dynamic (i.e. fully polymorphic); if you don't use the keyword `virtual` in your base class, the binding of the method will be static.

Comment: It will not be _fully_ dynamic; overloads (parameter types) will be selected at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of answers have said you make a base class function `virtual`, this is often done but not needed. you could just do the following...

```
class A{
public:
void foo();
}
class B: public A{
public:
void foo();
}
class C: public A{
public:
void foo();
}
```

If you had an array of A pointers such as `A* basePTR[2]` you can instance `basePTR[0]` as an instance of `B` then `basePTR[1]` as an instance of `C`. but if you tried to call `basePTR[0]->foo()` you will call `A::foo()`

if you defined `A` as

```
class A{
public:
virtual void foo();
}
```

then calling `basePTR[0]->foo()` will call `B::foo()`

Their is overhead for using this functionality as at run time a look up has to be done to see if you are calling the base functions `foo()` or a derived class's `foo()` but normally, this feature is worth the relatively minor performance hit.

You could define `A` as

```
class A{
public:
virtual void foo() =0;
}
```

the `=0` at the end of `foo()` means that this function is a pure virtual function, this means that it HAS to be defined by a derived class and you can't make an instance of `A`. A good example of where you would use this would be in a game, you might have a base class GameToken that has an XYZ position and a pure virtual function draw and update. from this you could derive `player` `AI` `dynamicObject` etc... your engine could then just store one array of type `GameToken*` and iterate through this array calling `draw()` and `update()` for all the different types in the array

Comment: `virtual` is needed because `override` in C# *means* polymorphism